# яндекс api map statusCode 403 Key is required

Tags: php, yandex-maps-api

Здраствуйте. Запрос на яндекс api возвращает 401 {"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Key is required"} с чем это связано ?

https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/search//v2/?callback=id_164612250612542115430&text=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%2C%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%2064-%D0%B9%20%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B8%2C%2034%20&format=json&rspn=0&lang=ru_RU&token=7efe4041d64eb5459a1c089113bf8cbe&type=geo&properties=addressdetails&geocoder_sco=latlong&origin=jsapi2Geocoder

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ключ из Кабинета разработчика надо прописать в подключении JS API на странице

Comment: Если же ключ указан, пришлите ссылку на страницу с кодом или соберите минимально демонстрирующий ситуацию пример. Также запросы с вашего сайта могут блокироваться со стороны Яндекса, если ранее были нарушения их пользовательского соглашения https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/terms/index-docpage/ В этом случае нужно уточнить ситуацию в поддержке - maps-api@support.yandex.ru